# Master-Detail and sounds

Tags: xcode, ios6

I'm new to Objective-C. My problem is I have an app in a Master-Detail design that has a table listing English words with their Welsh translations. That works great, but I also would like to add sound via a UIButton for the pronunciation. I know how to make one sound play, but how do I make the corresponding sound for the correct word play when I hit the button?

My table is as follows:

```
-(void)createWordData {
    NSMutableArray *nounWords;
    NSMutableArray *verbWords;

    _wordSections=@[@"Nouns", @"Verbs"];

    nounWords=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    verbWords=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [nounWords addObject:@{@"English":@"girl",@"Cymraeg":@"y ferch (f.)",@"Sound":@"Merch"}];
    [nounWords addObject:@{@"English":@"boy",@"Cymraeg":@"y bachgen (m.)",@"Sound":@"Bachgen"}];
    [nounWords addObject:@{@"English":@"cat",@"Cymraeg":@"y gath (f.)",@"Sound":@"Cath"}];
    [nounWords addObject:@{@"English":@"dog",@"Cymraeg":@"y ci (m.)",@"Sound":@"Ci"}];

    [verbWords addObject:@{@"English":@"walk",@"Cymraeg":@"cerdded",@"Sound":@"Cerdded"}];
    [verbWords addObject:@{@"English":@"run",@"Cymraeg":@"rhedeg",@"Sound":@"Rhedeg"}];
    [verbWords addObject:@{@"English":@"play",@"Cymraeg":@"chwarae",@"Sound":@"Chwarae"}];
    [verbWords addObject:@{@"English":@"sleep",@"Cymraeg":@"cysgu",@"Sound":@"Cysgu"}];

    _wordData=@[nounWords,verbWords];
}
```

The play action is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)pronunciation:(id)sender {

    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                           pathForResource:@"Cath" ofType:@"wav"];

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)
                                     [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile]
                                     , &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(soundID);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `pronunciation:` method, instead of hard-coding `@"Cath"`, make the choice of sound depend upon the facts about `sender` (or some other fact about the current state of things that determines which word is intended by the user).

By the way, making this sound an alert sound is probably not at all the best way to produce it. (And in any case you may be leaking your sound.) You should be using an AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: I could be more helpful if I knew more about where the call to `pronunciation:` is coming from. If there is just *one* button then presumably you will have to turn to the table view and ask which row is selected. But if there is a button in each row of the table view, you can discover which row this button (`sender`) is in. Either way, you then go from the row of the table to your (very nice) array-of-dictionaries model, and there you are.

Comment: Oh, and here's the section in my book about AVAudioPlayer: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch27.html#_audio_player

Comment: Sorry to keep at this, but it happens I've just written an app that does something quite similar: the user taps a rectangle and the corresponding sound plays. For that, I actually attached the name of the corresponding sound as an instance variable of each rectangle. So when the tap happens, there is no work to do at all: just look at the rectangle that was tapped, ask it the name of its sound, and play that sound. Just a matter of planning ahead.

Comment: The call to pronunciation: is coming from the last value in the table (@"Sound"). I was hoping to call it from there like I did with a label.

Comment: Hi Matt, just to clarify, there isn't a button in each row, but a single button on the detail view.

Comment: Right, so that's why I suggested using some other means to determine which sound the user intends to play (such as the selected row of the table, or whatever the interface is).

Comment: OK, like I mentioned before, I'm very new to this, so I'm not exactly sure how to select a row.

Comment: Well, stay with me here a moment. Tell me about the interface. Be the user. You see a table of words, do you not? How are you (the user) supposed to specify which word you want played?

Comment: There is a list of eight words split into two groups: Nouns and Verbs. When the user touches a row it displays the detail view with the Welsh translation in text. There's a button that they can click to play a sound file with the pronunciation.

Comment: Okay, so we are now in the detail view! So presumably you know *which* word we are displaying the details of. You must have handed that info to the detail view at the outset, otherwise it wouldn't be displaying the right word. So that is the word the user wants to play. You look that up in your model (array of dictionaries) and get the name of the sound.

Comment: I was just thinking, does my table need to have the sound files listed?

Comment: Yep, that's right. So, I'm wondering if my table is wrong. I have the variable @"Sound":@"Merch" where @"Merch" is supposed to be the wav file.

Comment: OK, so instead of having      NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                           pathForResource:@"Cath" ofType:@"wav"]; I should have  NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                           pathForResource:@"Sound" ofType:@"wav"];?

Comment: (Instead of "table" let's say "array" or "model" so we know we don't mean the UITableView!) You must have some variable in your detail view that tells you which word is currently showing, right? Let's say it is `@"walk"`. So now you have to cycle through both arrays (verbs and nouns, too bad you did that), looking for the one whose `@"English"` is `@"walk"`. When you find it, you fetch its `@"Sound"`. That will be  `@"Cerdded"` in this case. So now you can form the `pathForResource`!

Comment: OK, I think I know where you're going with this. Here is how I'm calling calling for e.g. @"walk" to produce @"cerdded".      if (self.detailItem) {
        NSString *wordCymraeg;
        wordCymraeg=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[self.detailItem objectForKey:@"Cymraeg"]];
        self.welshWord.text=wordCymraeg;
        self.navigationItem.title = [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"English"];
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.hidden=YES;}

Comment: So you are most of the way there because `self.detailItem` is the dictionary you want; you are 9/10 of the way there already. You still have this value, right? So `[self.detailItem objectForKey:@"Sound"]` is the very `pathForResource` we are after.

Comment: By the way it is pointless to say `[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[self.detailItem objectForKey:@"Cymraeg"]]` because you get exactly the same result by saying `[self.detailItem objectForKey:@"Cymraeg"]` all by itself.

Comment: Yes, I still have this value. So, forgive me, I'm a little thick. Do I add another string called *soundSomething ?
     if (self.detailItem) {
        NSString *wordCymraeg;
        wordCymraeg=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[self.detailItem objectForKey:@"Cymraeg"]];
        self.welshWord.text=wordCymraeg;
        [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"Sound"];
        self.navigationItem.title = [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"English"];
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.hidden=YES;}

Comment: When the user wants to play the sound you will start by saying `NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"Sound"] ofType:@"wav"];` (or whatever the type is) and now you can play that file.

Comment: Because, you see, in your model, the value of the `@"Sound"` key *is* the name of the sound file we want.